# Typed.js is Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, typed.js

I start typed.js but ist not working and no error shown in the console

```
$(function(){
    $('.animate-text').typed({
        strings:[
                "Muhammad Saim",
                "Programmer",
                "Web Developer",
              ],
        typeSpeed:0,
        loop:false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the ".animate-text" element/s are already rendered before executing your script.

Whenever you manipulate a DOM element , it needs to come before your javascript code.

Example that will not work :

```
<script> jQuery('#test').css('display','none');</script>
<div id='test'></div>
```

Example that will work :

```
<div id='test'></div>
<script> jQuery('#test').css('display','none');</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your script file and change the names according to you.

```
var typed = new Typed('#typed', {
  strings: [
    'Aman Singh Aswal'
  ],
  typeSpeed: 50,
  backSpeed: 80,
  loop: true
});
```

use this in html file where you want typedjs to work.